# Dynamic controller with "controller as" syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

If I want to assign dynamic controller, I can do the following:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-controller="dynamicController"></div>
</div>

function MainController($scope){
  $scope.dynamicController = MyCtrl;
  $scope.instanceName = "ctrl"; // we'll use this later
}

function MyCtrl(){}
```

**What can I do to make this work with the new "controller as" syntax?**

This works fine: `<div ng-controller="dynamicController as ctrl"></div>`

But how to make `ctrl` dynamic too? Let's say I want it to have a name that `$scope.instanceName` holds.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ftza67or/2/

There is an idea to make a custom directive that will create and compile html string, but it's an ugly way, let's pretend it does not exist.

Comment: Quick search on Google gave me http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/, and https://thinkster.io/egghead/experimental-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: @elclanrs i know how to use "controller as" syntax. My question is how to use it with dynamic controller reference.

Comment: Ah, I misread. Maybe you can check the `$controller` service. Using the name of the function seems like trouble, I'd try to use the name of the registered controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've looked into angular sources and found this.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/bf6a79c3484f474c300b5442ae73483030ef5782/src/ng/controller.js

```
 if (isString(expression)) {
    match = expression.match(CNTRL_REG),
    constructor = match[1],
    identifier = identifier || match[3];
    expression = controllers.hasOwnProperty(constructor)
        ? controllers[constructor]
        : getter(locals.$scope, constructor, true) ||
            (globals ? getter($window, constructor, true) : undefined);
  .... and so on
```

Basically, `ng-controller` directive currently accepts strings or expressions, if it is an expression, it has to be a controller function reference. If it is a string, well, it will take identifier name as it was passed and I don't see any way to make it evaluate a variable with dynamic expression name.

Answer (score 1):

This should work pretty much the same, but just remember that when you use `controller as` you can bind properties to `this` inside the controller to have them accessed by the scope/view.

```js
function MainController ($scope) {
  $scope.dynamicController = MyCtrl;
  }

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  this.foo = "baz";
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MainController">
  <div ng-controller="dynamicController as ctrl">
    {{ctrl.foo}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed that jsfiddle that i was using for testing was forked from one with old angular version. This works, yes.

Comment: BUT ) How to make controller instance name dynamic too? (the "as ctrl" part)

Comment: @Anri, why do you need the alias to be dynamic? It makes little sense. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @NewDev I have many "cards" in one page, and each card has it's own controller and cards are created in ng-repeater. So in card templates i want to reference correct controller. I guess I could use the same name for all, they are not nested YET, but still curious how to achieve that.

Comment: @Anri, you *should* try to use the same alias and not spaghetti-code your View, if at all possible, or minimize cross-dependencies by assigning meaningful role-based aliases to your controllers.

Comment: You can use $scope[dynamicNameVar] = MyCtrl;

Comment: @Anri The alias with `controller as` is like a variable -- you can't have dynamic variable names; that wouldn't make sense

Comment: @ExplosionPills well, yes, when you put it like that. But something like `<div ng-controller="dynamicController as {{ctrlAlias}}"></div>` looks pretty logical in angular template, except there is compilation and evaluation order problem

Comment: @Anri you could think about that as something like `var variableName = "variable value"` but then `variableName` would be interpolated somehow -- you can't do that!

Comment: @ExplosionPills well if I wanted to add dynamic aliases feature to angular, after parsing the expression I would just look up `$scope["ctrlAlias"]` and if it exists I would create `$scope[$scope.ctrlAlias] = $controller.get...`. If not, then `$scope["ctrlAlias"] = $controller.get...` as it does now. What is so hard or illogical in this?